# Linux Kernel Crypto Guide

Tags: c, cryptography, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a kernel module to encrypt/decrypt an input in kernel.
I am thinking about using the AES algorithm implemented in crypto.*(Any other suggestions for an efficient algorithms that can be found in Linux crypto?)*

I've searched for guides over the Internet and read the linux/crypto documentation but I'm still having problems understanding even the basics of how to use it(The linux kernel documentation about Crypto isn't much of a help..).

Can you please show me a website/guide/examples/even a little book on how to start this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example is gonna be useful for you: http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/cryptodev/cryptodev-20091126/

Comment: thank u very much for this .. it's still a bit hard to decode it and understand it's details and how it works for me.

Comment: if u had any guides or definitions I would applicate them very much <br> thanks again for your concern

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a trouble like you. But I have found this absolutely useful site about Crypto API Linux. Here is it:
http://www.chronox.de/crypto-API/

Comment: It is frowned upon to post link-only answers.  Please add something relevant from the linked web site to your answer.